# Verify backend calls from iOS app

Tags: ios, cloudkit, google-authentication, cloudkit-web-services

I am trying to find an equivalent of this Android verification but for iOS.

Initially posted in a [blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.au/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html)  but now incorporated into the main [android documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/CrossClientAuth#androidIdTokens), the verification lets you know 3 things:
Then, you know that:

1. The token was issued by Google.
2. The token was sent to a device that was being operated by the person identified in the payload's email field.
3. The token was obtained by the Android app identified by the Client ID in the payload’s azp field.

The key point is that:

> GoogleAuthUtil will observe that the Android app and the web client ID
>   are in the same project, and without user approval, return an ID token
>   to the app, signed by Google.

Therefore, I am able to verify backend calls, without disrupting the user.

Is there somethings similar for iOS from Apple, **where I can get a ID token signed by Apple when Apple  will observe that the iOS app and the web client ID?**

I have found a [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21832756/how-to-secure-app-backend-communications) trying to find something similar, but I am hoping for a simpler solution. That question was more than a year ago, so I am hoping there maybe a better answer, possibly with the new CloudKit web services.

Comment: The closest thing I've found is this: http://www.riskcompletefailure.com/2013/11/client-server-authentication-with-id.html , although this isn't quite the same as the Android equivalent that you mention, as this still requires the user to have a Google gmail account, which some of my iOS users may object to.  I've been looking for the same thing as you for months now without success: it looks like the only way to verify server comms without user approval is to invent a home-grown mechanism from scratch!

Comment: Hey, you can still do oauth2 getting essentially everything  http://www.raywenderlich.com/99431/oauth-2-with-swift-tutorial let me know what this looks like to you.

Comment: @yet did you find any solution for that. now i am facing similar issue please guide me how you achieved that

Comment: @bittoo, sorry I didn't

Comment: Are you talking about the ID to fetch push notifications?

Comment: why dont you use ssl certificates ? for verification request sent or received by google, and device id'z to verify valid user?

Answer (score 3):

Luckily I've come across [this thread on stackexchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/219028/how-to-safeguard-a-rest-api-for-only-trusted-mobile-applications) where the user [Iwaz](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/287622/iwaz) left a comment.

Iwaz is pointing at Apple's [DeviceCheck Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck) that can be used to verify if a call to your API comes from an actual installation of your iPhone App.

According to the docs it works as follows:

1. Get the current `DCDevice` by calling `DCDevice`'s `currentDevice` method.
2. From that `DCDevice` call its `generateTokenWithCompletionHandler` method to obtain a token.
3. Send that token along with your other data when making requests to your API.
4. In your API server code, call Apple's API by providing the token to validate it as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck/accessing_and_modifying_per-device_data).